# SonarQube is not collecting issues from Android gradle project

Tags: android, sonarqube, android-gradle-plugin, lint, sonarqube5.1

When I start `./gradlew sonar` it runs analyser and loads files, the project is added to sonarqube database with list of files, complexity etc. but no issues are created for the project. Android Lint (it has 147 rules added) is set as default list of issues and SonarQube way as default (and only) quality gate.

Full log:

```
sudokusolver git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew sonar
:app:sonarqube
INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app/build/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.2
11:48:48.324 INFO  - Load global repositories
11:48:48.552 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=234ms
11:48:48.554 INFO  - Server id: 20150807203003
11:48:48.557 INFO  - User cache: /home/agilob/.sonar/cache
11:48:48.565 INFO  - Install plugins
11:48:48.949 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
11:48:48.962 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
11:48:50.575 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
11:48:52.689 INFO  - Load project repositories
11:48:52.925 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=236ms
11:48:52.926 INFO  - Load project settings
11:48:53.265 INFO  - Load technical debt model
11:48:53.299 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
11:48:53.555 WARN  - 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.
11:48:53.574 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
11:48:53.576 INFO  - -------------  Scan SudokuSolver
11:48:53.583 INFO  - Load module settings
11:48:53.727 INFO  - Language is forced to java
11:48:53.739 INFO  - Load rules
11:48:54.981 INFO  - Base dir: /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app
11:48:54.981 INFO  - Working dir: /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app/build/sonar
11:48:54.982 INFO  - Source paths: src/main
11:48:54.982 INFO  - Test paths: src/androidTest
11:48:54.983 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_GB
11:48:54.983 INFO  - Index files
11:48:55.116 INFO  - 35 files indexed
11:48:55.304 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Android Lint
11:48:55.511 WARN  - ----------------------------------------------------------------
11:48:55.512 WARN  - Sonargraph: Skipping projectSudokuSolver [SusokuSolver], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
11:48:55.512 WARN  - ----------------------------------------------------------------
11:48:55.512 INFO  - Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
11:48:55.513 INFO  - Found SCM type: git
11:48:55.523 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor
11:48:56.119 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
11:48:56.122 INFO  - 34 source files to be analyzed
11:48:59.551 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 3432 ms
11:48:59.552 INFO  - 34/34 source files have been analyzed
11:48:59.552 WARN  - Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer. The org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DependenciesVisitor@6e61d22c are disabled.
11:48:59.553 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
11:48:59.553 INFO  - 1 source files to be analyzed
11:48:59.653 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 100 ms
11:48:59.653 INFO  - 1/1 source files have been analyzed
11:48:59.660 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=4137ms
11:48:59.660 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
11:48:59.673 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=13ms
11:48:59.674 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
11:48:59.680 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=6ms
11:48:59.680 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
11:48:59.689 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=9ms
11:48:59.689 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
11:48:59.701 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=12ms
11:48:59.702 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
11:48:59.721 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=19ms
11:48:59.722 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
11:48:59.723 INFO  - parsing /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app/target/surefire-reports
11:48:59.724 ERROR - Reports path not found or is not a directory: /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app/target/surefire-reports
11:48:59.724 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=2ms
11:48:59.725 INFO  - Sensor ScmStatsSensor
11:48:59.726 INFO  - Collection SCM Change log for the last 0 days
11:48:59.773 INFO  - Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app && git whatchanged '--until=2015-08-08 10:48:59 +0000' --date=iso -- /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app
11:48:59.774 INFO  - Working directory: /home/agilob/Projects/sudokusolver/app
11:49:00.107 INFO  - Sensor ScmStatsSensor (done) | time=382ms
11:49:00.107 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
11:49:00.108 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
11:49:00.108 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1ms
11:49:00.108 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
11:49:00.109 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
11:49:00.110 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
11:49:00.395 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=287ms
11:49:00.419 INFO  - Loaded quality gate 'SonarQube way'
11:49:00.456 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-08-08)
11:49:00.458 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-07-09, analysis of Fri Aug 07 23:19:57 BST 2015)
11:49:01.391 INFO  - Execute decorators...
11:49:02.036 INFO  - Store results in database
11:49:02.904 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 24ms, dir size=4 KB
11:49:02.934 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 30ms, zip size=14 KB
11:49:02.964 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 30ms
11:49:02.964 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/SusokuSolver
11:49:02.964 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 24.204 secs
```

My configuration added to main `gradle.build`

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.0"
}
}
```

My configuration added to `app/gradle.build`

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "SudokuSolver"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "SusokuSolver"
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
    property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
    property "sonar.language", "java"
    property "sonar.sources", "src/main/"
    property "sonar.tests", "src/androidTest/"
}
}
```

SonarQube is launched on embedded database, just for testing, but I don't think it matters.

When I start code analyser in IDEA, after >60seconds it gives me over 50 messages. Here I get nothing.

[image]

[Source code repo is available on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/agilob/sudokusolver/tree/master) it that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interested, I wrote [a short blog post](https://b.agilob.net/setting-up-sonarqube-for-android-gradle-project) about it which is more up-to-date than this answer.

Ok, I solved the issue. If you have the same problem, you must install mysql/postgress server on your machine, create database and user for SonarQube and the configuration in `app/build.gradle` must look as follows (I used MariaDB server):

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "SudokuSolver"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "SudokuSolver"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "SONAR_LOGIN"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "SONAR_PASSWORD"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/androidTest/"
        property "sonar.scm.provider", "git"
    }
}
```

After adding database config my project was properly analysed:
[image]